# Bootstrap input buttons wrap in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap-3, radio-button

There is a problem with Bootstrap buttons wrapping in IE8. The markup is as in official example:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="checkbox" checked> Option 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="checkbox"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

However, it results in the following:

[image: Bootstrap buttons wrapping in IE8]

Does anyone know if this is a known issue with an existing fix?

Answer (score 1):

Is there enough space for the buttons? Sometimes rendering of fonts and other differences in IE can throw things off. Perhaps forcing the display type would help.

```
.btn-group { 
    display: block; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, there's enough space. The problem occurs even on Bootstrap's demo page: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons. Applying suggested style didn't help.

Comment: I edited my answer with the css that works for me. I edited the CSS within IE8 developer tools and the buttons line up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I used the justified class and used the grid system to size it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-offset-9">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="ActionResult" id="ActionResult" autocomplete="off" value="A">
                Approve
            </label>
            <label class="btn btn-primary">
                <input type="radio" name="ActionResult" id="ActionResult" autocomplete="off" value="R">
                Reject
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```